# Addition of two variables with number_format

Tags: php

This is my first post on this forum so if i do something wrong, feel free to tell me.

I'm trying to move numbers to the point (2.2 / 150.25 for example) 
to numbers with commas (2,2 / 150,25).

After scouring the web, number_format seemed the best solution , everything works perfectly when I converted the numbers, but if I add them ( something that is essential to me ), the result is a number without commas or periods

This is my code :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
<?php
  function setMinutes($minutesNouv) {

  if ( $minutesNouv == 00 || $minutesNouv == 15 || $minutesNouv == 30 || $minutesNouv == 45 ) {
     $minutes = $minutesNouv;
  } else {
     $minutes = 0;
  }
 }
  function getHeuresDecimales($heures, $minutes) {
     $time = $heures + ($minutes / 60);
     $time = number_format($time, 2, ",", "");
     return $time;
 }

  function setHeuresDecimales($heuresD) {
     $heures = floor(floatval($heuresD));
     setMinutes((floatval($heuresD) - floor(floatval($heuresD))) * 60);
 }

 $heure = getHeuresDecimales(10, 30);
 $heure1 = getHeuresDecimales(3, 30);
 echo $heure . '<br>';
 echo $heure1 . '<br>';
 echo $heure + $heure1;

?>
 <body>
   <p>Convertir avec virgule</p>
 </body>
```

and this is the result :

10,50
3,50
13
Convertir avec virgule

I really do not know where it may come , if anyone can help me.

Comment: You return a formatted string that uses comma as decimal separator, where PHP wants a dot. PHP converts the numbers in the string until it encounters an invalid character (like comma) and stops...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i'm going to try another method.